# Image Upload PHP Code Error

Tags: php, forms, file-upload, image-uploading

My error log keeps showing an error in the PHP code for my image upload form.

I can't spot the error????

```
<?php
$target_dir    = "postingImages/";
$target_file   = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["postingImage"]["name"]);
$uploadOk      = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$check = getimagesize($_FILES["postingImage"]["tmp_name"]);
if ($check !== false) {
    echo "" . $check[""] . "";
    $uploadOk = 1;
} else {
    echo "  &#xd7; FILE IS NOT AN IMAGE";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
}
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
echo "  &#xd7; THIS IMAGE ALREADY EXIST ON SERVER";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
if ($_FILES["postingImage"]["size"] > 500000) {
echo "  &#xd7; FILE IS TOO LARGE";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
if ($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif") {
echo "  &#xd7; ONLY JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF FILES ARE PERMITTED";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
echo "  &#xd7; IMAGE WAS NOT UPLOADED";
} else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["postingImage"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo '<img class="fixed-ratio-resize" src="http://www.rebelplanetnews.com/postingImages/' . basename($_FILES["postingImage"]["name"]) . '">';
} else {
    echo "  &#xd7; IMAGE WAS NOT UPLOADED";
}
}
?>
```

The error keeps popping up on the 9th line of the code here:

```
      echo "" . $check[""] . "";
```

Again... I can't spot the error myself, so if anyone can help me understand what I am doing wrong here, I would greatly appreciate it..

Note: The form does work and uploads the image successfully. But I still get the error.

Comment: And what is the error? -_-

Comment: what do you expect from `$check[""]` to return??

Comment: @Fabien... I apologize... the error is... 'Undefined Index'.

Comment: Because you use `$check[""]` instead of `$check`?

Comment: Jeff, I agree with you. My 'web guy' added some line to the php when he was working for me which he claimed it needed. I saw that as well and questioned it. Forgive my ignorance, but I am still learning, so... I didn't want to just delete that 'if' section without asking someone more qualified than myself.

Comment: do a `print_r($check);` instead of the echo. then you'll see all the properties `getimagesize` returns in this array and you can access them like this `echo $check[0]` (will print the width)

Comment: ...and `echo "" . $whatever . "";` is the same thing as `echo whatever;`. The quotes aren't needed.

Comment: [here's the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php#refsect1-function.getimagesize-returnvalues) what you'll have in this array.

Comment: Thanks guys, but so far, exploring all of these suggestions, still getting error messages. I guess I'll just have to keep screwing around with that line and trying different things.

Comment: And if you just delete that line what happens? It doesn't seem to be outputting anything anyway...?

Answer (score 0):

You problem is the index of array $check[], you value can't be an empty string, replace by `$check[0]`

Here the code

HTML index.html

```
<form name="f1" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="postingImage"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

PHP upload.php

```
<?php
$target_dir    = "postingImages/";
$target_file   = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["postingImage"]["name"]);
$uploadOk      = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["postingImage"]["tmp_name"]);
    if ($check !== false) {
       echo "Image Size: ". $check[0] ."<br>";
       $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
       echo "  &#xd7; FILE IS NOT AN IMAGE";
       $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "  &#xd7; THIS IMAGE ALREADY EXIST ON SERVER";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
if ($_FILES["postingImage"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "  &#xd7; FILE IS TOO LARGE";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
if ($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != 
"jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif") {
     echo "  &#xd7; ONLY JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF FILES ARE PERMITTED";
     $uploadOk = 0;
 }
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "  &#xd7; IMAGE WAS NOT UPLOADED";
} else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["postingImage"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo '<img class="fixed-ratio-resize" src="postingImages/' . 
    basename($_FILES["postingImage"]["name"]) . '">';
} else {
    echo "  &#xd7; IMAGE WAS NOT UPLOADED";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Vladimir... 
unfortunately... your code prints (example) 'Image Size:527' at the top of the output.

Some of the other suggestions above also print code at the top of the output.

Comment: If you do not want to print code at the top just comment or delete the following line // echo "Image Size:". $ Check [0]. "";